# vimとemacsの異なる点をおしえてください

Tags: vim, emacs

テキストエディタを選びたいのですが
選ぶ判断の基準が見当たりません
どのような違いがありますか

Comment: できることはどちらもたいして変わらないでしょう。操作性の違いはありますが、これは好みの問題ですから…どんな環境で、どんな用途に使う、これが欲しいあれは嫌、といった条件を挙げていただくと、より具体的な回答がもらえるかもしれません。ところで、vimとemacsに絞っているのは何故でしょうか？

Comment: 「誰がか良いと言ったから」というのも悪くはありませんが、この件に関しては「自分で両方（他にも候補があるのであれば全て）を使ってみて、一番しっくり来たものを使用する」とした方が良いのでないかと思います。

Comment: 「スタックオーバーフローはプログラミンングの質問をするサイトです」と本家StackOverflowでは言われてしまうような質問ですね。姉妹サイトのSoftware Recommendationsで聞いてみるほうがいいのでは。英語ですが。

Comment: stackoverflow でも [黎明期には許容された](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430164)類のものではあるっぽいですね．それでも質問者は結構気を遣って質問しているようには見えますが．

Answer (score 6):

テキストエディタ比較は宗教戦争とも揶揄されるほど好みが割れる話題なので、ご自身で触ってみて判断されるのがベストだと思います。

公平性の程は保証できませんが、Wikipediaの [Editor war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war#Differences_between_Emacs_and_vi), [エディタ戦争](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%BF%E6%88%A6%E4%BA%89#vi_.E3.81.A8_Emacs_.E3.81.AE.E9.81.95.E3.81.84) などでも対比されています。

Answer (score 1):

VimとEmac両方使う人は少数派なので、適切な回答を得るのは困難です。

基準としては：

- 使用する言語で何方がより使われているか
- 好み

Ruby on RailsだとVimが優勢ですね。
両方試してみて自分の指に聞きましょう。

VimやEmacの様なeditorは目をつぶってコードが書ける部分が増えるのが利点です。しかし、目が辛いとか無ければタダの趣味です。カスタマイズするのにも時間を食います。

言語によってはIDEを使ったほうが生産性が上がります；一部にはVimやemacのcommandを使うためのプラグインもある。